# How to implement parametrized class templates with minimal boilerplate

Tags: c++, composition, template-meta-programming, boilerplate

In my software where template metaprogramming is used a lot, template classes often take class templates as arguments which define certain aspects of their behavior. As a very simple example, suppose we have a class `FormulaUser` which needs to use a formula to calculate a number from two other numbers, and the particular formula must be specified as a template parameter. Further, the formula needs to be open in regard to which data type it operates upon (float or double). For example:

```
template <template<typename> class Formula, typename FpType>
struct FormulaUser {
   using TheFormula = Formula<FpType>;

   void some_function ()
   {
       FpType x = 1;
       FpType y = 2;
       FpType result = TheFormula::calculate(x, y);
   }
};

template <typename FpType>
struct AddFormula {
    static FpType calculate (FpType x, FpType y) { return x + y; }
};

// composition:
using TheFormulaUser = FormulaUser<AddFormula, float>;
```

This is OK, but not so much when a formula itself needs to have parameters defined before being passed to the `FormulaUser`. For example, a `LinearFormula` (let's ignore the fact that floating point types can't be template parameters):

```
template <float A, float B, float C>
struct LinearFormula {
    template <typename FpType>
    struct Formula {
        static FpType calculate (FpType x, FpType y) { return A + B*x + C*y; }
    };
};

// composition:
using TheFormulaUser = FormulaUser<LinearFormula<1.0, 2.0, 3.0>::template Formula, float>;
```

What I don't like about this code is:

- Composition is ugly (the `::template Formula part`).
- The meat of the `LinearFormula` is indented twice.

Is there any way to make it nicer?

**UPDATE**

The reason I wish to split the formula parameters into two levels (the formula constants and the FpType) is that those in the first set are part of user configuration, while those in the second set are provided by the class that is making use of the Formula. Well, the FpType  also ends up as user configuration, but it should be the same for all formulas. This more complex composition demonstrates this...

```
using MyProgram = Program<
    float, // FpType
    AddFormula, // Formula for something
    LinearFormula<2.0, 5.3, 5.3>, // Formula for something else
    QuadraticFormula<.....>, // For something else...
    ExponentialAveraging< // AveragingType
        0.6 // SmoothingFactor
    >
>;
```

So you give the FpType to the root class, and it is propagated to everything else.

These examples are artifical but they should explain the problem. I don't want the configuration to have any more boilerplate than necessary (in particular, the float constants can't really be specified as above...).

Finally, it is a requirement that template metaprogramming be used (both for performance reasons as well as consistency with the existing code).

Comment: The double indentation and `::template` are a result of nesting, but you didn't motivate the nesting or even provide a valid illustration. The solution is obviously to avoid nesting, but we can't help solve that problem given this information.

Comment: It looks like you're in the solution space addressed by expression templates. You might look into how those are done. Composition is by function overloading, not nested template argument lists. Anyway, just my style, but regardless of the TMP complexity, I personally avoid exposing template template parameters to the user. There's almost always a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that your example is somewhat contrived, but I could see no reason for the template template parameters and the nesting. So my suggestion is to remove them and do all parameter type parameterization at the Formula level. This creates a 'neater' and less nested solution but maybe not one that is useful to you. Note also that I moved the floating point template parameters into a Policy Class.

```
template <class Formula>
struct FormulaUser 
{
    using param_type = typename Formula::param_type;

    param_type some_function()
    {
        param_type x = 1;
        param_type y = 2;
        return Formula::calculate(x, y);
    }
};

template <typename FpType>
struct AddFormula 
{
    using param_type = FpType;
    static FpType calculate(FpType x, FpType y) { return x + y; }
};

using TheFormulaUser = FormulaUser<AddFormula<float>>;

struct SomeCoefficients
{
    static float A()
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    static float B() 
    {
        return 2.0;
    }
    static float C()
    {
        return 3.0;
    }
};

template <typename FPType, typename LinearPolicy>
struct LinearFormula 
{
    using param_type = FPType;
    static FPType calculate(FPType x, FPType y) 
    {
        return LinearPolicy::A() + LinearPolicy::B() * x + LinearPolicy::C() * y; 
    }
};

// composition:
using TheFormulaUser2 = FormulaUser<LinearFormula<float, SomeCoefficients>>;
```

Comment: It's not useful to me because I need to be able to specify the FpType once in the FormulaUser. The FormulaUser may take many such classes that are open to FpType.

Comment: Just to be clear I'm suggesting moving from your syntax of `using TheFormulaUser = FormulaUser<AddFormula, float>;` to `using TheFormulaUser = FormulaUser<AddFormula<float>>;`. There's not much in it from a instantiation point of view. Any way if this won't help I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The FormulaUser composition is done in a file which is sort of user configuration, and it's not nice to have all those float parameters there (for the many formula choices).